# How to install previous plasma on Kubuntu 15.04?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma

I need to install KDE 4 on Kubuntu 15.04 instead of Plasma 5. How can I do this?

Comment: This is something I would love to see. I hate Plasma 5.

Comment: Normally you can not "downgrade" Ubuntu.

Comment: Bug #1451749 - Wish: provide a way to run kde 4 with vivid: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kubuntu-meta/+bug/1451749 . Status is: 'Won't Fix'

Answer (score 0):

the reply to the bug report linked by @user26687 says it's not possible. Wish it was.

The suggested workaround is to use the long term supported 14.04. Bäh.

A better workaround, which I found in the comments [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/615442/update-from-14-10-to-15-04-result-to-a-blank-screen-with-cursor-after-sddm-login/630562) is to install the gnome desktop until the bugs in kde5 are worked out:
`apt-get install gdm`